# how do I change my apk-file to another Name

Tags: android

I'm making my own App and reached the point of uploading Apk - file. But it did not succeed, I'm told, to use a different package name, how do I do it? Vh melanie

Comment: What's your package name? It needs to be unique (i.e. not a package name taken by another company). If you have a domain name then use that as your package prefix since it's highly unlikely that someone else will have used it.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Eclipse, Goto your project and  click on your package and PRESS F2 and rename to any other unique name. This is happen because you are using package name which has already been used.
Tell me if it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the package name in your code for all your java files. In `Android studio` you can just create a new package and drag and drop all your code into it and do a refactor, the changes will get automatically be applied to all the files rather than doing it manually.

Next go to the manifest and change the package to the new one you defined, this is where the play store would be looking into to identify your app. As the package name defines your application's identity, so if you change it, then it is considered to be a different application and users of the previous version cannot update to the new version. The package name should be unique.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="add.the.new.pakage.name.here".....
```